# maven install in eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven

I have a problem, because I wrote a little app in Intellij that uses native packages, except one the `org.json`. Right now there is a need to open it in `Eclipse` (let's assume `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)`). So I added a `pom.xml` file to the main directory of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>companyManagement</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When in Intellij under `Maven Projects` I will click `Generate sources and update folders` everything is fine. In `Eclipse` in the other hand, it is not. I have done:`File`->`new`->`Java Project`->`use default location` and pointed to the main folder (where amongst others is `pom.xml`). Next I've done:`right-click on pom.xml`->`run as`->`Maven install`. There is no problem with `maven-compiler-plugin`, but It seems that it doesn't download `org.json`. I've unchecked : `Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories`. What else I can try to make it fix ? because IDE still doesn't see `org.json` (and I would like to do that via maven)

EDITED
Actually I've changed version number to `20151123` and It seems to be ok, because `mvn install` returnes:

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.pom (5 KB at 7.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/json/json/20151123/json-20151123.jar (48 KB at 170.0 KB/sec)
```

But `import org.json.*` is still marked as unavailable (red underscore)

Answer (score 2):

On that case, you can try this. It may help you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of your dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an existing Maven project that you want to import into Eclipse, the best path is to use **File** > **Import** > **Maven** > **Existing Maven Projects** and then follow the prompts. That way you take full advantage of Eclipse's Maven integration, including using the pom to drive the Eclipse project dependencies.

Comment: Actually it worked, I have no idea why, but it worked, I normally skip this part (continue a subject when someone helped me and It worked), but `1`minute left so I'm not able to mark this question as accepted, so for future users I just put this comment. Thank you.